# Why have a PID controller for a DC servo motor?

Tags: control, pid-controller, motor-controller

Let's say i have a servo motor, and i send it an angle represented as a PWM. How can this system ever overshoot?

Will it overshoot when I try to increase the speed?

The steady state error can of cause be a reality, if something is holding the motor back.

I'm just a little confused of why i should use a PID or any other controller to the system, when i have feed back AND can send it a position

Br.

Comment: Are you reading the feedback? You use a control loop for not only removing a steady state error but for improving stability and settling time. Overshoot is a function of both the deceleration rate and inertia. By just setting a position and not using the feedback to close the loop you are just hoping it ends up where you want with no way to be sure.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That was actually my initial thought; that you are just hoping, with out a control system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are considering a complete servo mechanism which moves to the angle you tell it (eg. an RC hobby servo) then you don't need a PID loop because it already has one built in. In normal operation the servo's internal PID should prevent overshoot.

However, if you are controlling a *system* which might need varying servo positions to avoid overshoot or maintain stability, then you need an external PID loop. In this situation you could use an open-loop servo mechanism which is just a motor and feedback sensor.